# 'str' object is not callable for grouped df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to build a dictionary based on entity

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'entity': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'buzz', 'bar', 'buzz', 'foo', 'foo'],
    'value': [4, 3, 2, 1, 9, 8, 7, 4]
})
out = dict(df.groupby('entity'))
```

But I get the following error

```
   out = dict(df.groupby('entity'))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

What's wrong???

This is my pandas and python version

```
print(pd.__version__)
print(sys.version)
```

```
pandas == 1.5.3
sys == 3.10.9
```

Comment: A [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) prefers initialization by a "Mapping" to an iterable. I don't know exactly where a "Mapping" is defined, but the groupby object as a `.keys` parameter that holds the columns you use to group. In your case, its the string "entity". The `dict` constructor sees a .keys attribute and tries to call it, assuming its a function that lists the mapping's keys. But its a string, so boom. had you `groupby(['entity', 'value'])`, you'd get a `'list' object is not callable` instead.

Comment: Wow!  This is a more insight and good answer! I appreciate your time to explain this to me.

Comment: It had me puzzled too.

Comment: That's why I switch to this society, people always not only give the answer but try to find why this happens. Thanks again!

Comment: @tdelaney please write it up as an answer.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - jezrael added to his answer and that works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In old version of pandas need convert `groupby` object to `iterator` or tuples:

```
out = dict(iter(df.groupby('entity')))
```

Or:

```
out = dict(tuple(df.groupby('entity')))
```

---

```
print (out)
{'bar':   entity  value
1    bar      3
4    bar      9, 'baz':   entity  value
2    baz      2, 'buzz':   entity  value
3   buzz      1
5   buzz      8, 'foo':   entity  value
0    foo      4
6    foo      7
7    foo      4}
```

Better explanation by @tdelaney from commnents:

> A [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) prefers initialization by a "Mapping" to an iterable. I don't know exactly where a "Mapping" is defined, but the groupby object as a .keys parameter that holds the columns you use to group. In your case, its the string "entity". The dict constructor sees a .keys attribute and tries to call it, assuming its a function that lists the mapping's keys. But its a string, so boom. had you groupby(['entity', 'value']), you'd get a 'list' object is not callable instead.

Comment: Get this, and do you recommend to switch to pandas 2 ?

Comment: @wOw_python - I think best is use last version.

Comment: Cool. Let me check what's difference and how other people says.

Comment: To note, `dict` does not see the `tuple` as a Mapping, so iterates the tuple to create the dict.

Comment: I like this answer. I don't have any performance numbers but I think that `iter(df.groupby('entity'))` would be better than `tuple` for large dataframes where the intermeditate tuple would eat up space. It would also be more pandas version agnostic. Just guessing.

Comment: Yep, its the keys attribute. You can see it in action in the `dict_update_arg` function in [`dictobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/dictobject.c).